# Word to describe a story/myth that's often repeated but of doubtful authenticity

Tags: adjectives

I'm sure I came across a word that means exactly this before (I feel like it was a GRE word?), but I'm looking for a word that would describe  a story that people often retell because it's really cool, or it makes a point really well, although nobody really has any idea if it's true or not.

Unfortunately, google seems to interpret my searches as looking for stories about fake news.

Comment: What qualities make the word you're looking for different from "myth"?

Comment: You’re probably looking for ***apocryphal***

Comment: @fixer1234 urban myth ?

Comment: @Jim - How about writing an answer?

Comment: For future references, search a reverse dictionary such as http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word ***apocryphal*** is defined by [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apocryphal) as:

> 1. (of a story or statement) of doubtful authenticity, although widely circulated as being true.
>      *‘an apocryphal story about a former president’
>      ‘his alleged description of opera as ‘fat gits singing’ is probably apocryphal’*